# Type mismatch when comparing two variants, why?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have written a function that’s sole purpose is to loop through all forms in a continuous form, grab the names from an "Owner" field, and then create a collection out of them which only contains unique values (no repeated names).

The code below is my current code, I realize that this may seems to be a roundabout way to do what I want but some unforeseen issues prevent me from doing this the way I would like to.  So while I realize the code isn't super effective (and is very rough coding) I want to finish this path if only for a learning experience.  This line of code always gives me a type mismatch error message.  I have used a break line to see what those variables are in the local window, they both contain a string which should be the same therefore should return true.  I can't seem to find a way to make that comparison actually work.

```
    ElseIf var = o Then
```

The code (heavy commenting to make sure I am clear):

```
Private Sub Command39_Click()

    Dim intRecordCount As Integer
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim colNames As Collection
    Set colNames = New Collection

    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

    intRecordCount = rs.RecordCount

    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst


    If intRecordCount > 0 Then

        Dim thisCol As Collection
        Set thisCol = New Collection

        'For each record on the form
        Do While Not rs.EOF

            Dim str As String
            Dim o As Variant

            str = Me.txtOwners.Value & ""

            'If the textbox isn't empty
            If Len(str) > 0 Then

                'Send the string containing names ("Bob, Cheryl, Jeff, Tim")
                Set thisCol = SplitNames(str)

                'Loop through all of the names found
                For Each o In thisCol

                    Dim var As Variant
                    Dim blnFound As Boolean

                    'Loop through all names in the main collection
                    For Each var In colNames

                        'If the collection is empty simply add the first name
                        If colNames.Count = 0 Then
                            blnFound = False

                        'If the collection has items check each one to see if the name is already in the collection
                        'This line is where the problem lies, I can't find anyway to compare var to o
                        ElseIf var = o Then
                            blnFound = True
                        End If

                    Next var

                    'If the name was not found in the collection add it
                    If Not blnFound Then
                       colNames.Add (o)
                    End If
                Next o

            End If

            'Go to the next record in the continuous
            DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop

    End If


End Sub


'Accepts the name of the owners to be split
Public Function SplitNames(strNames As String) As Collection


    Dim colNames As Collection
    Dim strThisName As String

    Set colNames = New Collection

    'Replaces ("Bob, Cheryl, Jeff, Tim") with ("Bob Cheryl Jeff Tim")
    'I realize this isn't really needed simply my OCD requires I do
    strNames = Trim(Replace(strNames, ", ", " "))

    'Create the collection of names
    colNames.Add (Split(strNames, " "))

    'Send back the collection
    Set SplitNames = colNames

End Function
```

Update - For some reason I need to access the var string propery by using var(0) so it seems like somehow var became its own array?

Comment: You could use a Dictionary object instead of a collection. The dictionary object has an `.Exists` method which returns boolean value.

Comment: I will definitely give that a shot, because if that is the case I know of at least 4 other places I can use that haha.  Though do you see why that comparison doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I don't think that I can use the Split function to go into a dictionary can I?

Comment: I modified your SplitNames function to return *either* a Dictionary *or* a Collection, depending on what you want to work with. IT will always *use* a dictionary to ensure uniqueness, but can convert to collection if you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the updated code that works for what I need it to do.  I was adding a string array (being created by the Split() function) which was what I was adding instead of the string value itself.

```
Private Sub Command39_Click()

    Dim intRecordCount As Integer
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim dictNames As New Collection

    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

    intRecordCount = rs.RecordCount

    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst
    rs.MoveFirst

    If intRecordCount > 0 Then

        Dim dictTheseNames As New Collection

        'For each record on the form
        Do While Not rs.EOF

            Dim str As String
            Dim o As Variant

            str = Me.Controls("Text27").Value & ""

            'If the textbox isn't empty
            If Len(str) > 0 Then

                'Send the string containing names ("Bob, Cheryl, Jeff, Tim")
                Set dictTheseNames = SplitNames(str)

                'Loop through all of the names found
                For Each o In dictTheseNames

                    Dim var As Variant
                    Dim blnFound As Boolean
                    blnFound = False

                    'Loop through all names in the main collection
                    For Each var In dictNames

                        'If the collection is empty simply add the first name
                        If dictNames.Count = 0 Then
                            dictNames.Add (o)

                        'If the collection has items check each one to see if the name is already in the collection
                        'This line is where the problem lies, I can't find anyway to compare var to o
                        ElseIf o = var Then
                            blnFound = True
                        End If

                    Next var

                    'If the name was not found in the collection add it
                    If Not blnFound Then
                       dictNames.Add (o)
                    End If
                Next o

            End If

            'Go to the next record in the continuous
            rs.MoveNext

            If (rs.RecordCount - rs.AbsolutePosition) > 2 Then
                DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
            End If

        Loop

    End If


End Sub


'Accepts the name of the owners to be split
Public Function SplitNames(strNames As String) As Collection


    Dim dictNames As New Collection
    Dim strThisName As String
    Dim strArray() As String

    Set dictNames = New Collection


    'Replaces ("Bob, Cheryl, Jeff, Tim") with ("Bob Cheryl Jeff Tim")
    'I realize this isn't really needed simply my OCD requires I do
    strNames = Trim(Replace(strNames, ", ", " "))

    'Create the array of names
    strArray = Split(strNames, " ")

    Dim o As Variant
    For Each o In strArray
        dictNames.Add (o)
    Next o

    'Send back the collection
    Set SplitNames = dictNames

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of modifying your SplitNames function to a Dictionary object.

WHile there is an `Exists` method which you may make use of elsehwere in your code, you need not use that to ensure uniqueness. Merely *referring* to a Key will create it, so you can create a new key (or overwrite it if it exists) using the same method:

```
dict(key) = value
```

Note that this overwrites the *value* portion of the Key/Value pair.  But since your SplitNames function is merely building the "list" of unique names, I don't think that will be an issue.  For the sake of example, I simply assign nullstring to each *value*.

I added an optional parameter to this function to allow you to return *either* a Dictionary of unique names, *or* a Collection (converted from the Dictionary).  Untested, but I think it should work. Let me know if you have any trouble with it.

```
Public Function SplitNames(strNames As String, Optional returnCollection as Boolean=False) As Object
    'returns a Dictionary of unique names, _
    ' or a Collection of unique names if optional returnCollection=True

    Dim dictNames as Object
    Dim strThisName As Variant
    Dim coll as Collection
    Set dictNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Replaces ("Bob, Cheryl, Jeff, Tim") with ("Bob Cheryl Jeff Tim")
    'I realize this isn't really needed simply my OCD requires I do
    strNames = Trim(Replace(strNames, ", ", " "))

    'Create the collection of names
    For Each strThisName in  Split(strNames, " ")
        dictNames(strThisName) = ""
    Next

    If Not returnCollection Then
        Set SplitNames = dictNames
    Else
        Set coll = New Collection
        For each strThisName in dictNames.Keys()
            coll.Add strThisName
        Next
        Set SplitNames = coll
    End If
End Function
```

So I think you can reduce your procedure like so:

```
Private Sub Command39_Click()

    Dim intRecordCount As Integer
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim dictNames As Object
    Dim collNames as Collection
    Dim str As String
    Dim o As Variant

    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

    intRecordCount = rs.RecordCount

    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acFirst
    rs.MoveFirst

    If intRecordCount > 0 Then

        'For each record on the form
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            str = Me.Controls("Text27").Value & ""

            'If the textbox isn't empty

            If Len(str) > 0 Then

                'Send the string containing names ("Bob, Cheryl, Jeff, Tim")
                Set dictNames = SplitNames(str)

                'Alternatively, if you want to work with the Collection instead:
                Set collNames = SplitNames(str, True)

            End If
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```